# How do I update an AWS Gamelift script with boto3 in python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, unzip, amazon-gamelift

I am running into a problem trying to update an AWS Gamelift script with a python command that zips a directory and uploads it with all its contents as a newer version to AWS Gamelift.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
from os.path import basename
import boto3
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
    versInput = sys.argv[1]
    #initializes client for updating script in aws gamelift
    client = boto3.client('gamelift')

    #Where is the directory relative to the script directory. In this case, one folder dir lower and the contents of the RealtimeServer dir
    dirName = '../RealtimeServer'

    # create a ZipFile object
    with ZipFile('RealtimeServer.zip', 'w') as zipObj:
        # Iterate over all the files in directory
        for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(dirName):
            rootlen = len(dirName) + 1
            for filename in filenames:
                #create complete filepath of file in directory
                filePath = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
                # Add file to zip
                zipObj.write(filePath, filePath[rootlen:])

    response = client.update_script(
        ScriptId=SCRIPT_ID_GOES_HERE,
        Version=sys.argv[1],
        ZipFile=b'--zip-file \"fileb://RealtimeServer.zip\"'
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1])
```

I plan on using it by giving it a new version number everytime I make changes with:

```
python updateScript.py "0.1.1"
```

This is meant to help speed up development. However, I am doing something wrong with the ZipFile parameter of client.update_script()

For context, I can use the AWS CLI directly from the commandline and update a script without a problem by using:

```
aws gamelift update-script --script-id SCRIPT_STRING_ID_HERE --script-version "0.4.5" --zip-file fileb://RealtimeServer.zip
```

However, I am not sure what is going on because it fails to unzip the file when I try it:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the UpdateScript operation: Failed to unzip the zipped file.
```

UPDATE:

After reading more documentation about the ZipFile parameter:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/apireference/API_UpdateScript.html

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/gamelift.html#GameLift.Client.update_script

I tried sending a base64 encoded version of the zip file. However, that didn't work. I put the following code before the client_update part of the script and used b64EncodedZip as the ZipFile parameter.

```
with open("RealtimeServer.zip", "rb") as f:
        bytes = f.read()
        b64EncodedZip = base64.b64encode(bytes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by having some help from a maintainer of boto3 over at https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2646
(Thanks @swetashre)

Here is the code and it will only work up to 5mb and requires use of an s3 bucket if you want to upload a zip file any larger than that.

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
from os.path import basename
import boto3
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
    versInput = sys.argv[1]
    #initializes client for updating script in aws gamelift
    client = boto3.client('gamelift')

    #Where is the directory relative to the script directory. In this case, one folder dir lower and the contents of the RealtimeServer dir
    dirName = '../RealtimeServer'

    # create a ZipFile object
    with ZipFile('RealtimeServer.zip', 'w') as zipObj:
        # Iterate over all the files in directory
        for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(dirName):
            rootlen = len(dirName) + 1
            for filename in filenames:
                #create complete filepath of file in directory
                filePath = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
                # Add file to zip
                zipObj.write(filePath, filePath[rootlen:])

    with open('RealtimeServer.zip','rb') as f:
        contents = f.read()

    response = client.update_script(
        ScriptId="SCRIPT_ID_GOES_HERE",
        Version=sys.argv[1],
        ZipFile=contents
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the script working but I did it by avoiding the use of boto3. I don't like it but it works.

```
os.system("aws gamelift update-script --script-id \"SCRIPT_ID_GOES_HERE\" --script-version " + sys.argv[1] + " --zip-file fileb://RealtimeServer.zip")
```

If anyone knows how to get boto3 to work for updating an AWS Gamelift script then please let me know.